# How to make columns with independent cells from each other instead of rows?

Tags: html, css, cell, rows

Could anybody here tell me how to make columns with independent cells from each other instead of rows?

```css
table, tr, td {
background-color:red;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%"  >
    <colgroup>
        <col width="15%">
        <col width="15%">
        <col width="25%">
        <col width="35%">
        <col width="25%">
         <col width="25%">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td colspan="2">15</td>
        <td colspan="2">25</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">50</td>
        <td colspan="2">30</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you please show image of table with expected output. The problem statement is not clear

Comment: I would like to get a table like on this image: http://www.outsourcer.info/1.jpg

Comment: This is called mosaic pattern and it can be achieved by grid property not by table elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowspan` and `colspan` to create this layout.

You can also create this layout using `grid`property.

```css
body,
html {
  width: 99%;
  height: 99%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/400/300");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: solid white 8px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table class="container">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td colspan="2">3</td>
    <td rowspan="2">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td rowspan="2">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td rowspan="2">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td colspan="2">3</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is interesting, but there is some chaos and it is difficult to understand how to do exactly according to the layout table from image.

Comment: steps to create, first decide number of cols you want. Then create simple table consisting of tr and td. Them apply rowspan and colspan according to your requirement.  However this is try and error method.